# Middle-clicking to open link in a new tab in Firefox 15 does not work

Tags: firefox, mouse

When I booted up my laptop yesterday, the latest version of Firefox (15) was installed. Now, clicking the middle mouse button on a link is unresponsive.

I tried Chrome and it still works there.

(I'm wondering if this is at all related to the way that Firefox doesn’t recognize scrolling on the mouse pad—another mouse-related problem.)

Comment: Could you add your operating system to the question (preferably as a tag)?

Answer (score 2):

Thank Logitech in my case. New update to their Mouseware software changed the middle button from standard middle click to "Universal scroll"

The OP may want to look into their mouse software to see if any buttons have been reprogrammed to act differently.

Hope my problem and solution is helpful to others...

Answer (score 0):

If the problem source is Firefox, then this should work:

- Go to `Options` > `Advanced` > `General` and check `Use
  autoscrolling`.
- If it doesn't fix the problem, create a new Firefox profile and restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this problem today passing from an old wired Logitech to a new Logitech M705.

The solution was to download the Logitech software and set the Middle Button to "Middle Button"

[image]

Not sure why but by default it was set to "Zoom"